# How to model a hand crank generator in LTSPICE?

Tags: capacitor, ltspice, brushless-dc-motor

I built the following circuit that uses a small BLDC motor (3-24V AC) to generate enough energy to light an LED for roughly 40 seconds once C1 is charged to 5V and the generator stops.
[image]

It takes about 5 turns (270 degrees) of the motor to reach 5V. If I turn even faster I could reach 7-9V but it seems to be stable at 5V due to the increased current flowing through the LED.

Now I'm trying to simulate this in LTSPICE to understand this better as I want to replace the LED/Resistor with a low powered MCU (3.3V at 1mAh constant current draw) to see if its feasible.

I can't figure out how to go about modeling this. I'm thinking about just using a PULSE voltage source to represent the motor (after 3 phase rectification). Here is what I gathered from my oscilloscope when I gave the motor a spin while connected to a 10K resistor (after 3 phase rectification)
[image]

- Rise time: 100ms
- Fall time: 260ms
- Peak: 17.70V

Additionally, how do I represent the limited current? With a 10K resistor I'm able to only pull 10mAh.

Comment: Is that oscilloscope plot with or without the capacitor?

Comment: Without the capacitor

Comment: Are you more concerned about the loading effects on the source or just the best way to draw that waveform in LTspice?  If it's the latter, you can actually export the scope data to a CSV and import it into LTspice as a PWL source.  If it's the former, if you restrict yourself to a relatively small range of load currents, you can probably use Thevenin's theorem to create a linearized equivalent source.  It's going to depend on how accurate you want the model to be.